# Delete many-to-one using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Given the example of Unidirectional 1-1 mapping of Person with a single address listed below, what is the right way to delete an address from a person and have the database record deleted?  Setting the shipAddr field to null results in a NPE.

```
// pseudo code that results in NPE
ses.beginTransaction();
person.setShipAddr(null);
dao.makePersistent(person);    
ses.getTransaction().commit();
```

**Solution:** Revised pseudo code based on Hibernate docs that orphan delete is not supported for single valued one-to-one or many-to-one associations.

```
 // correct pseudo code 
ses.beginTransaction();
addressDao.makeTransient(person.getShipAddr());    // explicitly delete address
person.setShipAddr(null);
dao.makePersistent(person);    
ses.getTransaction().commit();
```

Class definitions:

```
class Person {
  private Long id;
  private Integer version;
  private Address shipAddr;
  // other fields
}

class Address {
  private Long id;
  private Integer version;
  // other fields
}
```

Mapping files:

```
<class name="Person" >
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
<version generated="never" name="version" type="java.lang.Integer" />
    <many-to-one name="shipAddr" class="Address" cascade="all-delete-orphan" unique="true" not-null="true" >
        <column name="SHIP_ADDRESS_ID" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>

<Class name="Address" >
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <version generated="never" name="version" type="java.lang.Integer" />
</class>
```

Exception when saving after setting address to null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.EntityEntry.getLoadedValue(EntityEntry.java:255)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:232)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:127)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:376)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:112)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
at com.easa.motordb.dao.internal.GenericHibernateDAO.makePersistent(GenericHibernateDAO.java:93)
at com.easa.motordb.services.internal.AbstractEntity.save(AbstractEntity.java:103)
at com.easa.motordb.services.test.IPersonEntityTest.removeAddress(IPersonEntityTest.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:62)
at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.CoreTestApplication.run(CoreTestApplication.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: try by removing "not-null="true"" in many-to-one tag 
also post full stack trace and versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`. It should be used when you have a collection of child entities, which you want to be removed when the parent entity is removed, thus *orphaned*, so I think it is not supported for `many-to-one` associations. I suggest you remove the address manually.

EDIT:  Official documentation says: *Note that single valued many-to-one associations do not support orphan delete.* under ***5.1.7. Mapping one to one and one to many associations***

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and think about my question.  Changing cascade to "all" prevented the NPE but the original issue remains as the address is not deleted from the database.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to that section of the docs.  I was focused on section 8.2.2. One-to-one Association Mappings to find what I was doing wrong.

Comment: So you have to remove the address by your self?no way to do this directly when deleting or updating a Person?